# Size of struct members

Tags: c

I have a struct like

```
struct T {
    int first, int second
} Tstruct;
```

now i want to define somewhere

```
pointer = struct.base + sizeof(Tstruct.second);
```

but i get error telling me put ")" befor "." , what is my mistake here? Sizeof(Tstruct) is working... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in your question you might want the `offsetof` macro that is guaranteed to exist.

```
char* pointer = (void*)&Tstruct;
pointer += offsetof(struct T, second);
```

It also has the advantage to take care of possible padding between the fields.

If you really want to do what you say in your question, if you have C99 you can use a *compound literal*:

```
pointer += sizeof ((const struct T){ 0 }).second;
```

here `((const struct T){ 0 })` is a temporary of the struct type, but who's creation will be optimized out by any C99 conforming compiler without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you can use `sizeof(int)` or even `sizeof(struct.second)` (assuming `struct` is an instance of `struct T` with an illegal name).

`sizeof` operates on both types and expressions. `sizeof(Tstruct.second)` is neither a type nor a valid expression. However, given a valid instance of `Tstruct` the following is an expression whose type is the type of `Tstruct::second`:

```
Tstruct properly_named_struct;
sizeof(properly_named_struct.second);
```

Comment: are you sure `struct.second` ? how will it work if multiple structs present ?

Comment: @Pheonix: The OP is using `struct` as an instance of type `TStruct`. `sizeof` can work on both types an expressions, and `struct_instance.member` is an expression whose type is the type of `member`. So other than the illegal naming in his example code, yes it will work.

Comment: I found this, its perfectly working #define member_size(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member) ,but thx for help.

Comment: `struct` is a reserved keyword, so it can not be used as instanciation name.

Comment: @tristopia: Yes, yet the OP bogus sample code does. This is mentioned both in my answer and my comments, thank you for mentioning a third time for those in the back.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof ( TStruct.second ) is perfectly valid.

struct.base isn't because struct is a reserved keyword in C and should point to the member name of the structure.